# Probability of selecting $k$ points such that the resulting polynomial $H$ satisfies $H(0)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, probability-theory, statistics, polynomials, lagrange-interpolation

I read that $k$ points on some finite field $\mathbb{F}$ completely determine a $k-1$ polynomial $H$ in $\mathbb{F}[x]$, and the polynomial can be computed using Lagrange interpolation.

Suppose that I uniformly sample these $k$ points and use Lagrange interpolation to get $H$. What is the probability that $H(0)=0$ ? ... My guess is that this probability is very small....

Comment: Presumably this is a finite field?  "Uniformly sample" doesn't make sense for an infinite field.

Comment: Hint: adding some field member to all $k$ values also adds the same constant to $H(0)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, yes it is a finite field ... thanks

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thank you for the hint, but am having difficulty since am relatively new to polynomials ... any additional help ?

Comment: The point is that for any $y \in \mathbb F$ this gives a one-to-one mapping from the $k$-tuples that produce $H(0)=0$ to those that produce $H(0) = y$.  What does that say about the probabilities?